# Need to extract values for each user using key-value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, key-value

Working on getting the right score to appear on each user>show page.

I am using a `helper_method :high_scores` in the application controller, like this:

```
def scores
   User.joins(submissions: :score).maximum(:sub_total, group: 'users.id')  
end
```

And this returns:

```
{6619=>"5", 6608=>"50", 6601=>"10", 6598=>"15", 6594=>"20", 6582=>"20", 6574=>"5", 6565=>"15", 6553=>"20", 6549=>"10", 6543=>"5", 6527=>"10", 6476=>"10", 6467=>"20", 6465=>"20", 6447=>"15", 6414=>"25", 6404=>"20"...}
```

With user_id as the key returning the value of highest score for that user.

Then, I want to render each members high score in the user show template as:

```
 <%= contest_score %> contest points<br/>
```

Or something like that.

I don't know how to extract the values. That may sound pretty simple, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<% contest_scores.each do |(user_id, score)| %>
  <%= user_id %>
  <%= score %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the heavy lifting in the applications controller, then use `high_score` in the view? I need to use it in two places and I need to be able to add the high_score to another integer.

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirements are. `contest_scores` contains a list of all users' highscores.  to get a high score for a particular user, use `contest_scores[user_id]`.  you may want to cache that method into an instance variable so you only fetch it once

Comment: Thanks! I needed to know the syntax.